# Do $n=2m+1$ and $\big(2^m\bmod(m\cdot n)\big)\in\{n+1,3n-1\}$ imply $n$ prime?

Tags: number-theory, pseudoprimes

Do $n=2m+1$ and $\big(2^m\bmod(m\cdot n)\big)\in\{n+1,3n-1\}$ imply $n$ prime?

Equivalently, for $n=2m+1$, do $2^m\equiv\pm1\pmod n$ and $2^m\equiv2\pmod m$ imply $n$ prime?
<sub>Note: equivalence follows from the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) for $m>2$, and examination otherwise. $2^m\equiv\pm1\pmod n$ is an [Euler test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_pseudoprime) for $n$.</sub>

What if we add the stronger requirements that $2^{(m-1)/2}\equiv\pm1\pmod m$ ? That $m$ pass the [strong pseudoprime test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_pseudoprime) to base 2?

---

The $n$ with $m$ prime that pass the test include all the [safe primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_prime) (OEIS [A005385](https://oeis.org/A005385)) above $5$. The corresponding $m$ are [Sophie Germain primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain_prime) (OEIS [A005384](https://oeis.org/A005384)).
<sub>Proof: safe primes $p=2q+1$ match $2^q\equiv\pm1\pmod p$ by [Euler's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion), and match $2^q\equiv2\pmod q$ by [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem).</sub>

I fail to prove that conversely, the $n=2m+1$ with $m$ prime that pass the test include nothing but the [safe primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_prime).

There are a few other $n$ that pass the test, dubbed *pseudo-safe-primes*, [A300193](https://oeis.org/A300193); terms less than $2^{42}$ [b300193](https://oeis.org/A300193/b300193.txt); first ones:

```
683, 1123, 1291, 4931, 16963, 25603, 70667, 110491, 121403, 145771, 166667, 301703, 424843, 529547, 579883, 696323, 715523, 854467, 904103, 1112339, 1175723, 1234187, 1306667, 1444523, 2146043, 2651687, 2796203, 2882183, 3069083, 3216931, 4284283, 4325443, 4577323, 5493179, 5764531, 9949943,
```

The smallest even $m$ are for $n=252\,435\,584\,573$, $1\,200\,060\,997\,853$, $2\,497\,199\,739\,653$, $453\,074\,558\,824\,253$... which are prime. Any such even $m$ is an even pseudoprime (OEIS [A006935](https://oeis.org/A006935)).

All odd $m$ are pseudoprimes (OEIS [A001567](https://oeis.org/A001567)) passing a [Fermat test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_primality_test), with the corresponding $n$ passing a [strong pseudoprime test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_pseudoprime).

Comment: You might not like the number $m=23456248059221$ :-)

Comment: @Peter Košinár: that's an answer to two of out of the three questions! $n=2m+1=(2^{47}+1)/3=283*P_{12}$. Further, $m=(2^{46}-1)/3$ pass the Euler test. All that's left pending is: does there exist composite $n=2m+1$ with $n$ and $m$ passing the strong pseudoprime test?

Comment: As you have correctly observed, I used the standard construction $m=(4^p-1)/3$ for Fermat pseudoprimes and just tested $n=(2m+1)$ for non-primality. While it guarantees $m$ to satisfy Euler criterion too, it fails the extended Euler-Jacobi version of it where $\pm 1$ is replaced by Jacobi symbol (and thus also fails the strong pseudoprimality test). When I tried to do something similar with one specific explicit construction of strong pseudoprimes, it failed miserably: the resulting $n$ failed even the Fermat test. I will keep playing with a few more ideas, though.

Answer (score 3):

After [Peter Košinár's answer/comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2673678/35016#comment5532212_2673678), it is settled that the answer to the title's question is *no*. And that even the stronger requirements: $n=2m+1$, $2^m\equiv\pm1\pmod n$, and $2^{(m-1)/2}\equiv\pm1\pmod m\ $ do *not* imply $n$ prime. Many of the $m=(4^p-1)/3$ with $p$ prime turn out to be counterexamples, including $p$ among

```
23, 29, 41, 53, 89, 113, 131, 179, 191, 233, 239, 251, 281, 293, 359, 419, 431, 443, 491, 509, 593, 641, 653, 659, 683, 719, 743, 761, 809, 911, 953, 1013, 1019, 1031, 1049, 1103, 1223, 1229, 1289, 1409, 1439, 1451, 1481, 1499, 1511, 1559, 1583, 1601, 1733, 1811, 1889, 1901, 1931, 1973, 2003,
```

---

It holds that if $n=2m+1$ with $m$ prime and $2^m\equiv\pm1\pmod n$, then $n$ is prime. That's proven by Fedor Petrov [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/295517/122065), with details [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2697758/35016).

---

Question remaining open: do $n=2m+1$, $n$ and $m$ passing the [strong pseudoprime test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_pseudoprime) to base 2 imply $n$ prime?